# Raman Spectroscopy of Graphene

Tags: material-science, graphene, raman-spectroscopy

Why do graphite and graphene have different peaks in Raman Spectroscopy? Does a double layered graphite give us a graphite peak or a graphite peak?

Answer (score 0):

A double-layered graphite structure would still exhibit the characteristic peak associated with graphite. The peak arises from the arrangement of carbon atoms in a layered structure within graphite, where each carbon atom is covalently bonded to three neighbouring atoms, forming a hexagonal lattice.

The presence of additional layers in a double-layered graphite structure would not significantly alter the overall arrangement of the carbon atoms or the bonding pattern within each layer. As a result, the characteristic graphite peak, which is typically observed in X-ray diffraction or other structural analysis techniques, would still be present.

However, it is worth noting that the intensity or shape of the peak may vary depending on the specific structural arrangement and the quality of the double-layered graphite material. Different types of graphite structures, such as turbostratic graphite or few-layer graphene (Carbon fibers derived from polyacrylonitrile (PAN) are **[turbostratic](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Carbon_fibers)**), can exhibit variations in the peak shape due to the disorder or stacking order of the layers.

Graphite, graphene and C60 are all forms of carbon allotropes, with distinct structures and properties. Graphite consists of stacked layers of graphene, which are two-dimensional sheets of carbon atoms arranged in a hexagonal lattice. Graphene, on the other hand, is a single layer of carbon atoms.  **These make excellent conductors and semiconductors, while C60 shaped like a soccer football makes an excellent insulator and lubricant additive.**

Raman spectroscopy is a technique used to analyze the vibrational modes of molecules or materials. It is based on the Raman scattering phenomenon, where a sample interacts with light, and the scattered light undergoes energy shifts corresponding to the vibrational modes of the sample. By analyzing the scattered light, valuable information about the molecular structure, bonding, and composition of the sample can be obtained.

When applied to graphite and graphene, Raman spectroscopy can provide insights into their structural and electronic properties. Graphene exhibits distinct Raman spectra due to its unique lattice structure. The most prominent Raman peak in graphene is the G band, which corresponds to the in-plane vibration of carbon atoms in the hexagonal lattice. The intensity and position of this peak can provide information about the number of layers, defects, strain, and doping in graphene.

Another important Raman peak in graphene is the 2D band, which represents the second-order scattering process involving two [phonons](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Phonon_scattering). The intensity ratio between the G and 2D bands can be used to determine the number of layers in graphene and differentiate between single-layer graphene, few-layer graphene, and graphite.

In the case of C60, also known as fullerene or buckyball, Raman spectroscopy can be used to characterize its vibrational modes. C60 is a spherical molecule composed of 60 carbon atoms arranged in a structure resembling a soccer ball. Raman spectroscopy can identify the characteristic vibrational modes of C60, such as the Ag(2) mode and the Hg(2) mode, which correspond to the stretching and bending vibrations of carbon bonds in the molecule.

Overall, Raman spectroscopy is a powerful tool for characterizing the structural and electronic properties of carbon-based materials like graphite, graphene, and C60, providing valuable insights into their composition, defects, and physical properties.